# facet_wrap_paginate x axis off place in last page

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, ggforce

The problem that I'm facing is that with facet_wrap_paginate on the last page the x axis is at the bottom of the picture, and not at the bottom of the plot.

**Page 1**

```
ggplot(diamonds) +
    geom_point(aes(carat, price), alpha = 0.1) +
    facet_wrap_paginate(~cut:clarity, ncol = 3, nrow = 6, page = 1)
```

[image]

And this is the last page:

**Page 4**

```
ggplot(diamonds) +
    geom_point(aes(carat, price), alpha = 0.1) +
    facet_wrap_paginate(~cut:clarity, ncol = 2, nrow = 6, page = 4)
```

[image]

As you can see the "carat" label is at the bottom rather than together with the plots. Any solution for that?

Thanks!

Comment: My understanding is that it intentionally tries to make all pages' plots the same dimensions. For this, the space between the actual x-axis and its label on page 4 is really "empty facets". I can certainly see the utility in doing it the way you want, though, perhaps a [feature-request](https://github.com/thomasp85/ggforce/issues) is justified? (I know I'd +1 that request.)

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, it seems to me that the package is a bit forgotten (?) so I might try to code it myself. I'll let you know if I'm able to do it.

Comment: Where do you get that idea? It was just updated last month.